# Microsoft PowerPoint 2007/2010 - Default Key Change

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How to change default key shortcuts? I've got presenter, whitch is binding "Play" button to F5 - it starts presentation from beginning - I want to start it from current slide (Shift + F5).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you must use a third-party add-in, such as [OfficeOne Shortcut Manager 4.0 for PowerPoint](http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html) ($29.95, trial available).